# How $^3\text{He}$ atoms remove thermal energy from surrounding environment in dilution refrigerator?

Tags: thermodynamics, superfluidity, low-temperature-physics, cryogenics

I am trying to understand how a dilution refrigerator works.

I understand that $^3\text{He}$ atoms are pumped out of the diluted phase and to reestablish an equilibrium, new $^3\text{He}$ move there from phase which is $^3\text{He}$-rich. To do so, $^3\text{He}$ atoms have to overcome a barrier, hence they need energy which is gained from surrounding environment. As a result, a temperature of the environment decreases.

Since a heat transfer from a colder body to a hotter one without external work input is forbidden by the second law of thermodynamics, my question is where is this work comes from in case of the dilution refrigerator?

Is the energy delivered by pumping $^3\text{He}$ atoms or does second Heisenberg relation $\Delta E \Delta t \ge \hbar/2$ play a role? Or both (firstly the atoms overcome the barrier with help of quantum tunneling and the energy deficit is "paid down" with pumping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a $^3$He liquid in thermal contact with a $^3$He gas dissolved in a $^4$He liquid. Evaporating the $^3$He liquid into the gas phase requires latent heat, which is extracted from the environment. We can promote evaporation by pumping on the $^3$He/$^4$He mixture.